# ImageViews not aligned after resize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I have to align horizontally in the center|bottom of the activity two imageviews and I have to resize the imageviews in a screen width percentage (ex. 10% of screen width).

If I don't apply the resize, I have two imageviews in the center|bottom, but too big;
if I apply the resize, I have only the first in the center; the other one is disappeared!

I've tried to use Linearlayouts (orientation = horizontal) and Tablelayout...no results!

This is my activity XML when I'used the Tablelayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoCosoft"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_cosoft" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoFeelife"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_feelife" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This is my activity XML when I've used the Linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearSplash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoCosoft"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_cosoft" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoFeelife"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_feelife" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java code when I've used the Linearlayout:

```
int DisplayWidth = Funzioni.ScreenWidth (SplashScreen.this);
int DisplayHeight = Funzioni.ScreenHeight(SplashScreen.this);

imgLogoCosoft = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogoCosoft);
LayoutParams params_imgLogoCosoft = new LayoutParams(DisplayWidth,(DisplayHeight/100)*10);
imgLogoCosoft.setLayoutParams(params_imgLogoCosoft);

imgLogoFeelife = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogoFeelife);
LayoutParams params_imgLogoFeelife = new LayoutParams(DisplayWidth,(DisplayHeight/100)*10);
imgLogoFeelife.setLayoutParams(params_imgLogoFeelife);
```

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No suggestions, but just a thing:
Replace `(DisplayHeight/100)*10` by `(DisplayHeight/10)` :)

Comment: Thanks, I will change this redundant code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer to myself.

For the tho images to place and resize at the bottom of the activity, instead of

```
LayoutParams params_imgLogoCosoft = new LayoutParams(DisplayWidth,(DisplayHeight/100)*10);
imgLogoCosoft.setLayoutParams(params_imgLogoCosoft);
```

I've used

```
imgLogoCosoft.getLayoutParams().width = DisplayWidth/10;
```

This is the XML of the Activity:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgSfondoSplash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/back_splash" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pgbSplash"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgSfondoSplash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoCosoft"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_cosoft" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogoFeelife"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_feelife" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code of the activity:

```
imgSfondoSplash = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSfondoSplash);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_imgSfondoSplash = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(DisplayWidth,(DisplayHeight/100)*90);
imgSfondoSplash.setLayoutParams(params_imgSfondoSplash);

    imgLogoCosoft = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogoCosoft);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_imgLogoCosoft=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((DisplayWidth / 10), (DisplayWidth / 10));
    lp_imgLogoCosoft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imgLogoCosoft.setLayoutParams(lp_imgLogoCosoft);

    imgLogoFeelife = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLogoFeelife);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_imgLogoFeelife=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((DisplayWidth / 10), (DisplayWidth / 10));
    lp_imgLogoFeelife.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp_imgLogoFeelife.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imgLogoCosoft);
    imgLogoFeelife.setLayoutParams(lp_imgLogoFeelife);
```

I hope this could be useful for other developers.

Comment: Just a note: There's no need to edit the title to include "solved". If you mark the answer as accepted, it will automatically show up as solved to others.

Comment: Thanks, Geobits...I'm newbie. :-)